# How to run Celery schedule only a number of times and quite until the task is called again?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I am using django + celery task scheduler to run a task scheduled for once every month. But I just want this task to run for a few number of months only, e.g 3 months or 6 months or 9 months..

How do I get to stop the worker from executing further task and then restarting whenever the task is called again?

here's my task

```
@task(name="add_profit")
def count():
    portfolios = Portfolio.objects.filter(status='ACTIVE')
    if portfolios.exists():
        for portfolio in portfolios:
            user = portfolio.user
            #calculates portfolio profit
            amount = portfolio.amount * 0.1
            if portfolio.duration == '3 Months':
                PortfolioProfit.objects.create(user=user, amount=amount)
                user.useraccount.account_balance += amount
                user.useraccount.save()
```

and here's my celery task schedule

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes 1st day of every Month.
    'every-minute': {
        'task': 'add_profit',
        # crontab can be changes to change Schedule
        # http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html
        'schedule': crontab(0, 0, day_of_month = 1),
    },
}
```

Comment: just for readability you might rename `'every-minute'` into `'every-month'`

Comment: I thought I understood the question. Since you added the code snippets I'm not that sure.

It seems now, that you want to call the celery task every month, and that some actions within the task for certain  portfolios should be only executed a limited amount of time.

The answers, that I gave you so far were for calling a celery task only for a certain number of months.

Could you please clarify.

If you want to perform tasks on one specific portfolio only for a limited amount of time, then it would be best to change the model such, that you can store whether it still needs calling.

Comment: Basically these tasks will be triggered randomly by the users. depending on the duration of the portfolio they select, then this task will add a certain amount to their account balance every month, some for 3 months, some for 6 months..etc. and these tasks should run for all the portfolios that have an active status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a new answer. I want to keep the previous one for the record as it might help other people having a different problem. For your question I think you just have to call the celery task every month unconditionally.

I think easiest would be if you change the data stored in the database such, that you can identify active portfolios, that you store the date of the first time and one date for the last time you automatically want to add a value.

Now the monthly celery task will identify users for which first_date <= today <= last_date and add the value if the condition is true.

Comment: Thanks. I think this pattern should work, but will it work if i use a timedelta value for the last date?

Comment: will work as well in that case you'd do:
`first_date <= today <= first_date + time_delta`

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
you start the task every month with a celery crontab entry and within the task you add a test: if the current date is not within a certain range you just quit processing.

This has a slight overhead, but a sight overhead once per month should be acceptable.

```
@task(name="add_profit")
def count():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    if today > datetime.datetime(2020,1, 1):
        return
    # the remaining part of your task follows here
```

Option 2:
You execute once (with or without a for loop) a small code snippet, that schedules the tasks for the months in question.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

In below I example I just show the idea with scheduling a task for the next three days:

```
today = datetime.utcnow()

for delta in range(1, 4):
    task.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2, ...), eta=today + timedelta(days=delta))
```

Here the task will be executed exactly as often as you want.

However if you migrate the server to a different location, if you reset rabbitmq (or whatever broker you have) the tasks to be scheduled will be lost / will disappear

Comment: Hi @gelonida, Thanks for your response.

Comment: I have just updated My question and added codes to it because i am quite unsure how to implement your solution since I am just a beginner. I have the task and the scheduler shown. from the task if the portfolio.duration is 3 months, I want to run this task 3 times and quit the schedular. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

ok. thanks alot @gelonida for your input. I have been able to achieve my goal.

I created a database input of the expiry date (3months, 6months etc, depending on the selection of the user), which is computed using the date the portfolio was created and sometime in the future as follows:

```
portfolio.expiry_date = timezone.now() + timedelta(days = 93) # for 3months
```

then in my task i did this

```
from django.utils import timezone


@task(name="add_profit")
def count():
    portfolios = Portfolio.objects.filter(status='ACTIVE')
    current_datetime = timezone.now()
    if portfolios.exists():
        for portfolio in portfolios:
            if current_datetime > portfolio.expiry_date:
                portfolio.status = 'COMPLETED'
                portfolio.save()
                return
            else:
                user = portfolio.user
                amount = portfolio.amount * 0.1
                PortfolioProfit.objects.create(user=user, amount=amount)
                user.useraccount.account_balance += amount
                user.useraccount.save()
```

This worked perfectly for me.